# math - dynamic chart, maintain constrain proportions

Tags: php, css, dynamic, charts

i'm creating a very simple dynamic bar-chart ( CSS / PHP ) where basically what i need to display is the total number of user contacts where each bar-width is the number of the contacts in px (each contact = 1 pixel) very trivial no?

```
 _______.____________________600px
|       |                        |
| mario | ===== (54) px          |
| julie | ========= (65) px      |
| john  | === (40) px            |
| mary  | ============= (70) px  |
|_______|________________________|
        0%   30%   50%   80%   100%
```

now, my problem is that the graph-container should be of fixed width let's say 600px, so, what happen if one of theese have more than 600 contacts? yes i know, it screw up. ;-)

so, how to convert to percentage in a way that each total scale accordingly and never reach the end of the graph?

thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sum all of your values (54 + 65 + 40 +70 = 229), calculate the percentage of each value (54/229 = 23.58%), and then apply that percentage to 600px (600 * .2358 = 141.48). You can then set that value as the width of your bar (so the first bar would be 141px).

In code it might look something like this (although you would probably calculate these values in a loop):

```
$total = 229;
$bar1 = 54;
$bar1Length = round(600 * ($bar1/$total)); // 141
```

Comment: hi, i have another little question, what is the formula if i want to add below the chart a classic visual percentage like 0% - 10% - 20% - ... - 100% always based on 600? thanks dude!

Comment: `$bar1/$total` will give you the percentage as a fraction (e.g. 0.754) to get something similar to 74%, multiply it by 100 and round. So something like `round(($bar1/$total)*100) . "%"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like

> current_width = current_value * (max_width / max_value)

Where max_width = 600px.

Note that this is just pseudo code. I can't write down anything specific, because your question doesn't provide any details.

Answer (score 1):

If the width available for the bars is `totalWidth`, you do something like this (in C pseudocode, I don't know PHP):

```
int maxContacts = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
{
    if (users[i].numberOfContacts > maxContacts)
        maxContacts = users[i].numberOfContacts;
}

// now you have the max number of contacts

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++)
{
    widthPercent = users[i].numberOfContacts / maxContacts; // this is the percentage
    display_width_for_this_user = totalWidth * widthPercent; // gives the relative width
}
```